# Convert JObject to custome entity - c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON that is returned from an API call:

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "Message": null,
    "Nodes": [
        {
            "Title": "Title 1",
            "Link": "http://www.google.com",
            "Description": null,
            "PubDate": "2014-06-19T13:32:00-07:00"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Title 2",
            "Link": "http://www.bing.com",
            "Description": null,
            "PubDate": "2014-06-26T13:14:00-07:00"
        },

    ]
}
```

I have the following object to convert the JSON to an custom object

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Nodes")]
    public IEnumerable<object> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to execute the following line of code to deserialize to the `MyApiResponse` object.

```
MyApiResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyApiResponse>(json);
```

I would like to loop through the `Nodes` property of the `MyApiResponse` object can serialize them into another object.  When I try the following snippet of code it throws an error:

```
foreach(var item in response.Nodes)
{
     MyObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(item.ToString());
}
```

What do I need to do to convert `item` into my `MyObject` in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: so your question is why it throw error? if yes please provide the error message. Or your question is : What do I need to do to convert item into my MyObject in the foreach loop? if this, since u declare it as Nodes in the class MyApiResponse, if you want to change to something else for sure you need to convert it

Comment: @ah_hau - It looks like the API is throwing a HTTP 500 error when I try to loop through the `Nodes` property to convert them to the `MyObject` data type

Comment: can you post more code? HTTP 500 Internal Server Error is generic server error, if you already receive your response, why it still calling the web function? Did your JsonConvert calling 3rd party converter that hosting online?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define a class to represent a Node, then change the `Nodes` property in your `MyApiResponse` class to be a `List<Node>` (or `IEnumerable<Node>` if you prefer) instead of an `IEnumerable<object>`.  When you call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyApiResponse>(json)`, the whole JSON response is deserialized in one go.  There should not be a need to deserialize each child item individually.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Node
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PubDate")]
    public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Nodes")]
    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
MyApiResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyApiResponse>(json);

foreach (Node node in response.Nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Title);
}
```